# Pass shell variables to SQL statement

Tags: sql, shell, sqlplus

I want to pass shell variables to sql statement. Both shell script and SQL statement are present in the same script file.
I want the values of the variables `retMonth`, `retLastDay` and `retPrvYear` in the SQL statement.
Below is the code.

If I execute this, it prints  `- " partition_date between '01--' and '--' \ 0 0] 1 1] 12-DEC-14 1"`

How can I have values of `retMonth`, `retLastDay` and `retPrvYear` in SQL statement?

```
echo $retMonth  //This prints 07
echo $retLastDay //This prints 31
echo $retPrvYear  //This prints 2015

count=$(sqlplus -s  ${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID} <<END
#connect ${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID}
set serveroutput on
set linesize 1000
set heading off
set feedback off
define lastMonth=$retMonth
define lastYear=$retPrvYear
define lastDay=$retLastDay
SELECT count(1)
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE partition_date between '01-$lastMonth-$lastYear' and '$lastDay-$lastMonth-$lastYear'
  );
END
)
```

Comment: Even double qoutes is not working. Its giving the same output

Answer (score 0):

Try using quoted shell variables directly without using `define` directives:

```
count=$(sqlplus -s "${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID}" <<END
set serveroutput on
set linesize 1000
set heading off
set feedback off

SELECT count(1)
  FROM MYTABLE
  WHERE partition_date between 
   "01-$retMonth-$retPrvYear" and "$retLastDay-$retMonth-$retPrvYear";
END
)
```

Comment: It worked to an extent. Now its printing `AND PARTITION_DATE BETWEEN '01-7-2015' AND '31-7-2015' \ 0 0] 1 1] 12-DEC-14 1`.

Comment: After trying your updated ans, it now prints `AND PARTITION_DATE BETWEEN "01-7-2015" AND "31-7-2015" \ 0 0] 1 1] 12-DEC-14 1`. I dont understand why its printing `\ 0 0] 1 1] 12-DEC-14 1`

Comment: What gets printed if you just keep `"01-$retMonth-$retPrvYear" and "$retLastDay-$retMonth-$retPrvYear"` between `<<END` and closing `END`?